# capture Azure blob storage logs in azure cosmosdb

Tags: azure-functions

we need to capture the file details and event times in azure cosmos db whenever there is modification in azure blob storage. for example, i deleted one file from azure blob storage and that information need to capture in azure cosmosdb in one container. i tried with event grid trigger azure function but didnt worked for me. Could you please provide azure function example for this scenario

Answer (score 0):

You will need an Event grid topic together with an Azure function. You haven't mentioned if you created that.

I would suggest you follow the steps mentioned in the [quick start tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/blob-event-quickstart-portal).

In your case, your event handler would be an Azure function to which you need to write to Cosmos using either output binding or the SDK.

Example of output binding : [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-output?tabs=csharp)

Example of SDK python : [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-api-python-samples)

Example of SDK .NET : [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-api-dotnet-v3sdk-samples)